# Need a good mobile phone simulator

Tags: asp.net, mobile, simulator, mobile-browser

I am developing a mobile website using asp.net mvc 4 for the first time. A few pages are already developed. Now I need to test this website.

Can please somebody let me know which is the best simulator? If something is available such that I can test iphone, blackberry, htc, Samsung android, nokia lumia, etc all on the same simulator? If not, then which would be the best ones for each or separate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check all device simulator [here](http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-simulators)

Answer (score 0):

For all the above mentioned platforms, official SDKs contain simulators, and I bet you won't be able to find better ones.

For Android, use the simulator that comes with [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

For Windows Phone, use the simulator that comes with [Windows Phone SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the Opera Mobile Emulator

http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/

I use it and is helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you could use the emulator but it's really really slow. 
But a fast one for android is running it in Virtual Machine. 
http://virtualboximages.com/Android+OS+2.6.29+x86+Virtual+Appliance

Comment: Now that I test my mobile website in various emulators I see that the design does not appear correctly in all devices. If i adjust for one then the other goes bad. I am developing a mobile website for the first time. I need to fit my design in devices of all resolutions. For example if I have a form with 2 text boxes in the same line and i test this in iphone it looks fine but if i use a nokia phone, the 2 text boxes appear in 2 separate lines.   Also for any page i do not want a scroll to appear so that the user has difficulty in browsing. Please help.